# linux ubuntu 18.04 lamp php and python cgi

Tags: php, python, ubuntu, lamp

operating system linux ubuntu 18.04
now I've installed the lamp and can run php codes seamlessly. the directory I'm running / var / www / html.
but what i want to do is run python cgi. I have reviewed several sources but I have not succeeded.

Comment: There's a lot of documentation on this. I suggest you try some of those out, and get back here if you're stuck with actually executing some code. Otherwise, [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) is a good place to post server-hosting issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with the following:

1). Install libapache2-mod-python

```
$ sudo apt install libapache2-mod-python 
$ sudo a2enmod python
```

2). Add this to a new file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ -- changing the relevant parts to whatever suits you

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # 
    ServerName yourpythonserver.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/py

    <Directory /var/www/py>
        AddHandler mod_python .py
        PythonHandler index
        PythonDebug On
        DirectoryIndex index.py
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

3). As you can see from the config above, this will serve requests directed to `yourpythonserver.com` from `/var/www/py` - defaulting to index.py

4). Create the file `/var/www/py/index.py` with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from mod_python import apache


def handler(req): 
    ret = ""
    req.content_type = "text/html"
    req.write("<h1>Hello World!</h1>")
    return apache.OK
```

5). Finally,

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

This is where it starts to get fuzzy for me, but perhaps someone else out there can help us both out with this... I'm not sure *why* the name of the function needs to be handler, and I'm not sure how to get things PHP normally provides such as `$_SERVER` variable. 
But either way, this works and will serve python files using apache.